# How to delete multiple Datasets in AWS Cognito android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I tried deleting the datasets in AWS Cognito using dataset.delete() and then synchronize it in **for loop** for each dataset. Is there any api function in AWS sdk to delete all or multiple datasets and then sync them with one synchronize function ?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not currently supported.

You may refer to the following for more information or updates to the API:

- The service API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDataset.html
- The open-source AWS Mobile SDK for Android https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/tree/master/aws-android-sdk-cognito